# Paypal how do I get PayerID using credit card payment method

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I am using Paypal REST, PHP SDK master.
This question concerns payments.

I need to know how to get the PayerID when I am 
using the "credit_card" payment method.

If you look in the PHP SDK under samples/payments
you will see two sample files, CreatePayment.php and 
ExecutePayment.php. These samples run independently.

Here is what I  want to do. 
In CreatePayment.php I want call ExecutePayment.php.
At the bottom of the CreatePaymet.php file I would have
a line something like this.

```
 header( "Location: ExecutePayment.php?success=true&PayerID=ABC12345678
```

The question is, where do I get the PayerID?

Now, I have this working using payment method paypal.
(In the SDK see CreatePaymentUsingPayPal  )
The way that works is you give it redirect urls for
return and cancel (you do not supply approval_ur)
Then, down at the bottom of the file it has
this code where it loops through the payment object's links,
and gets the approval_url.

```
foreach($payment->getLinks() as $link) {
   if($link->getRel() == 'approval_url') {
      $redirectUrl = $link->getHref();
      break;
   }
}

if(isset($redirectUrl)) {
   header("Location: $redirectUrl"); 
   exit;
```

}

The $redirectUrl (approval_url) is something like this,
and control will transfer to there.

< https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-12345678AB5432123>

When control returns to your site, you will
see that the return url that you specified,
now has the PayerID and token appended to the end of it.
In other words, paypal service supplies you with the 
PayerID and automatically appends it to your 
return url.

That is how it works using payment method of paypal.
Now, the question is, how do I get PayerID using 
payment method credit card?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you use the PayPal payments , it is two step process where you will get the Payer ID after the buyer approves the Payment on the PayPal checkout page , then you will use that id to charge their PayPal account .

But Credit card Payments are one step process where you will submit the create request to the PayPal with the credit card and the other information and the transactions will be done at the same time. So there is no "execute" step involved for the credit card payments .

Comment: When I call ->create() method , transaction is successful, but merchant account funds is remaining the same. What could be the issue ?

Comment: @d123546 same problem funds remaining the same. how you solve this issue?